# Find the mean and the variance of a sum

Tags: variance

Suppose Y_n is distributed (μ_n, σ^2), where the covariance between any pair (m, n) is 0.5*σ^2.
Find the mean and the variance of B = sum(n=1 to N) of (k_n*Y_n),
where the k_n (n=1 to N) are constants.

--- Not sure whether this is correct, I tried to solve it, but I have serious doubts about it. ---

In case of independence of the two variables  Y_n and Y_m,

σ_mn=0  and therefore, σ_mn=0.5*σ^2=0 (is this true?)

The mean (expectation) of B is,

Ε(B)=Ε(∑_(n=1) up to N of (k_n Y_n )=∑_(n=1) up to N (k_n Ε(Y_n))

= ∑_(n=1) up to N of (k_n μ_n )

The variance of B is,

V(B)= Ε([B-Ε(B)]^2 )
= Ε[(∑_(n=1) up to N (k_n Y_n )-∑_(n=1) up to N of (k_n μ_n )^2 ]

= Ε[(∑_(n=1) up to N(k_n (Y_n-μ_n ) ))^2 ]

Looking for a more elegant, correct and detailed solution...

Comment: Your question shows some effort but is hard to read. Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical formatting. Moreover, it is unclear if the sample you consider is a [Gaussian vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution). Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The random variable $B = \sum_{n=1}^Nk_nY_n$ is a linear combination of Guassian random variables.  Its mean is given by $$E[B] = \sum_{n=1}^Nk_nE[Y_n] = \sum_{n=1}^Nk_n\mu_n.$$  And its variance is 
\begin{align*}
  & \text{Var}[B] = \text{Cov}(B, B) \\
= & \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^Nk_ik_j\text{Cov}(Y_i,Y_j).
\end{align*}
From your first assumption, $\text{Cov}(Y_i,Y_j) = \sigma^2(1+\delta_{ij})/2,$ thus $$\text{Var}[B] = \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N\sigma^2k_ik_j(1+\delta_{ij})/2 = \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N\sigma^2k_ik_j/2 + \sum_{i=1}^N\sigma^2k_i^2/2.$$  For the case where $Y_n$ and $Y_m$ are independent $(n \ne m)$, $\text{Cov}(Y_i,Y_j) = \sigma^2\delta_{ij}$, then
$$\text{Var}[B] = \sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^Nk_i^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the $y_n$ are elements of a Gaussian vector, that is
$$
P(\mathbf{y} ) \propto e^{\mathbf{(y-\mu)}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{(y-\mu)}/2 }
$$
where $\mathbf{\mu}$ is the vector of mean values and $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is the covariance matrix, which is equal to 
$$ \mathbf{\Sigma}=
\pmatrix {1&\frac12&\frac12 &\cdots& \frac12 &\frac12\\
\frac12&1&\frac12 &\cdots& \frac12&\frac12\\
\frac12&\frac12 &1&\cdots& \frac12&\frac12\\
\frac12&\frac12&\frac12& \ddots& 1 &\frac12\\
\frac12&\frac12&\frac12&\cdots &\frac12&1
}
$$
The the way to do this is to note that you can change variables based on the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{\Sigma}$, which are 
$$\frac1{\sqrt{N}}\pmatrix{1\\-1\\-1\\ \vdots \\-1\\-1}, 
\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1\\1\\0\\ \vdots \\0\\0}, 
\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1\\0\\1\\ \vdots \\0\\0}, 
\cdots,
\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\ \vdots \\1\\0}, 
\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\ \vdots \\0\\1}, 
$$
to 
$$
x_1 = \frac1{\sqrt{N}}(y_1 - y_2-y_3-.\cdots-y_N)\\
x_2 = \frac1{\sqrt{2}}(y_1-y_2)\\
x_3 = \frac1{\sqrt{2}}(y_1-y_3)\\
\vdots\\
x_N = \frac1{\sqrt{2}}(y_1-y_N)\\
$$
These new variables are independent, and have $\sigma^2$ equal to the corresponding eigenvalues of $\mathbf{\Sigma}$  which are respectively
$$ (\frac{N+1}{2}, \frac12,\frac12, \cdots \frac12$$

So the variance of the sum is 
$$
\sigma^2 = \frac{N+1}{2}+ (N-1) \frac12 = N
$$
The mean of the sum is, of course, the sum of the means.